# How to make recursive function in c# for reading data from db

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to write a Recursive Function that will end up reading data records from a db.
Each Records has a number but they are not necessary sequential; For Example:
I can get [1-30, 40-50, 60-70].
My Goal is to get x records no matter their sequence number.
Notice the records must have a high order so if for example I receive 1-30 I cannot get a lower number than 30 (only 31 or higher).

Function input is : (int from, int count):
i must return count records.

So my algorithm fills the holes with the next valid record number.
So in my example of [1-30, 40-50, 60-70].
Records 31-39 will point to record 40, 51-59 -> to 60 etc..

```
public int[] GetRecords(int start, int count)
{
     int[] readfromdb = Read(50); // reads 1-50 ([31-39 points to 40])
        ????
}
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why recursion? This sounds more like a sequential task to me. You should always prefer iteration over recursion if it is possible.

Comment: @oliver smells like homework to me, so maybe that's why.

Comment: if its recursive, then what's the base case, running out of records? And how does it know what records to get or skip or whatever? There are a lot of unknowns about your requirements.

Comment: Does not require recursion.  Use  list<> to allow you to add data randomly.  With SQL databases data is not retrieved in order so always use a OrderBy to get the data sequentially.